# Google api client->authenticate doesn't work

Tags: php, google-api, access-token

I try to use google youtube api. Everything is OK. But with $_GET["code"] i cannot get access token. Relative code snippet :

```
require ('XXX/vendor/autoload.php');
                    $client = new Google_Client();
                    $client->setApplicationName("XXX");
                    $client->setAuthConfig('XXX/client_secrets.json');
                    $client>addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
                    $redirect_uri = 'XXXX';
                    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
                    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
                    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                            $test = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

                    }
echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                     <a href="'.$auth_url.'" style="border-radius: 5px;padding-left: inherit;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;width: 127px; display: block;" class="yutub" ><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <span class="social-text">YouTube</span><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i></a></div>';
```

I can write $_GET["code"] in file. But authenticate doesn't work properly. I read EVERY document about it. How can i overcome it ?? My redirect page is this page.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to the auth URL that is being created. try using this after u created ur auth URL

```
header('Location:'.$auth_url);
```

Then you should be redirected to google's auth site where the user authenticates himself. After that you put this piece of code on your redirect page

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $test = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

}
```

Also, make sure your client id and secret + redirect URL are set correct.

Comment: I go it in html part and it returns with code which exchange for access token

Comment: Can you post your entire code please, Is your redirect page also the same as this page?

Comment: This page is my redirect page

Comment: remove the $test variable just make it like this:
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

after that line you put this:
$test = $client->getAccessToken();

Comment: Execution is stopped in $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); line :(

Comment: so then its working no? try doing this: if($client->getAccesToken()) {echo "done";}

Comment: Done is not appear , i get $_GET['code'] but didn't exchange it for a accesstoken in authentication method. And program stop in there. İn addition , getAccesstoken doesn't work because of this.