# Google API client->authenticate () error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I was fiddling around with the **Google (calendar) API**. I created a small script so I could import my timetable to Google Calendar, it worked fine... on localhost. Since I wanted to try to make it work for other people too, I uploaded everything to a server, but it just doesn't want to work.

I changed the config file paths, the redirect uri's and the client secret JSON from the dev. console.

It doesn't work, it simply doesn't.

`$client->authenticate ($_GET['code']);` doesn't run.

Below you can see a file I called callback.php. It's almost a one to one copy from a Google Dev. site. (inside domain.com/import)

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('../../client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/import/callback.php');

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $client->authenticate($code); // <- If I comment out this line, it 'works' fine
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

In Chrome I'm getting an `HTTP 500 ERROR`, even with `error_reporting set to E_ALL`. In Firefox (mobile) I just get a blank page (even if I want to `var_dump / echo` something).

I transferred everything to my localhost again (updated client_secret.json) and everything works just fine. My (shared hosting) server's error log is empty.

I would really appreciate your help with this problem.

I checked with my webhost; They say the server time is accurate, so that couldn't be the problem.

My webhost told me they changed their settings. I had to define my error logging in an `.htaccess file`. So I did.
I'm getting Curl error 60, now. I have tried many of the solutions the internet has provided me with, yet. But none of them seem to work. I'm almost giving up (partly because of my webhost).

PS:
Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` is not a valid solution, for me. And it shouldn't be, for anyone.

Comment: we need to see your code to be able to help you debug it

Comment: @DaImTo, I added a piece of my code! :)

Comment: [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783404/google-api-client-authenticate-doesnt-work)
 seems to have the same issue, but there's no solution nor an usable answer.

Comment: I'd speak to your Webhost and see why a 500 error doesn't create a log

Comment: @thebluefox I updated my post, thanks for trying to help out!

Comment: cURL error 60, as you probably know if you've been Google'ing, is an issue with SSL certificates. You need to configure `curl.cainfo` on your server in your `php.ini` file so that it points to a root certificate bundle. This is something I would have thought your host would have had configured from the word go, however.

Comment: @thebluefox - I know, I found this solution too, but (obviously) my webhost doesn't allow me to write a PHP.ini file. I can use an .user.ini file, but it doesn't seem to work. I guess I should just change webhosting providers, shouldn't I?